# Where Can I give Entities in Amazon Lex ? Is Slot the other name for entity mentioned in Amazon Lex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

Every Bot works on NLP. So, Intent and Entities are must to create a bot. I found Intents in the Amazon Lex. but i didnt find entities. Slot is the other name for entity? Can anyone explain me what is intent and entity in detail with Lex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following explanation may help you understand the concepts Intent and Entity:

Intent is a task or an action a user want to perform, for example, I want to book a cab or want to order the food.

**Book a cab** and **order the food** are intents. These intents have the entities called cab(vehicle), food(pizza). Intents will tell you what user wants to do whereas entities will help you with how to do?

In Amazon lex, **Slot** is a section where you can mention the entity and the values for the entity.

Example:

**Intent**: Book a cab

This is a task a user wants to do.

**Entity**: Cab

Values for the entity is Micro, Mini, Prime.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some helpful definitions that are used in chatbots and specifically Lex:

**Dialog** = the conversation between the bot and the user.

**Utterance** = input sent from the user to the bot.

**Response** = returned message from the bot to the user.

**Intent** = an organized group of utterances that helps the bot recognize what the user wants.

**Slot** = (also called "entity") a parameter within the utterance to provide more specific details to the intent.

**Slot Type** = an organized group of numbers, letters, words, or phrases that help the bot recognize the value to be passed as a parameter in a Slot.

**Slot Value** = the number, date, word, or phrase taken from the utterance and saved in a Slot.

Example:

> *User:* I'd like to order a pizza.

The bot takes this user input and processes the utterance by comparing it with all of the intent utterances to best match the user input with the correct intent. The intent may have closely matched this utterance set up in the bot: **"I want to order a {food}."**

The bot recognizes the value of "pizza" within the utterance as matching a value in the **Slot Type** possibly named "foodTypes". The Lex bot then delivers this information to Lambda including **User Input**, **Intent**, **Slots**, and **Slot Values**.

The logic built into Lambda or other endpoint, handles the information to form a response. You should validate and parse the user input and slots yourself to improve the NLP accuracy and correct any mistakes. Then deliver a response back to Lex, which then delivers the response message to the user.

From this example, the information gathered could be this:

> **User Input** = I'd like to order a pizza.
>
> **Intent Utterance** = "I'd like to order a {food}."
>
> **Intent** = pizzaOrderIntent
>
> **Slot Type** = foodTypes
>
> **Slot** = food
>
> **Slot Value** = "pizza"

Comment: @Jay-a-little I have a query. I want to give inputs from the lex and the lex has to invoke a function in lambda which in turn store the values in DynamoDB. And in return when user asks to cancel his ticket(For example) then it has to retrieve the ticket no from DynamoDB and has to display in the lex bot. I started first integrating lex to lambda. But after my first dialog itself lambda response is sent on lex bot stating that response is null. How to handle that ?

Comment: @CharanKumar That's a pretty generic error so there are many possibilities of where the bug is. Basically it means that whatever is being returned (to Lex from Lambda) was not sent, was empty, or had incorrect formatting. So I suggest logging your response and checking CloudWatch to help narrow the search down. Then post a new question here with that data if you need help debugging the response.